# Is Minio S3 api is compatible with Amazon's S3

Tags: amazon-s3, object-storage, minio

I want to have my own private hosted object storage with S3 compatibility.

Now I found [minio](https://www.minio.io/) as a solution. My question is: If I have an application A that is able to connect to amazon S3 storage does that imply that I could also connect to minio?

More specifically if minio created a presigned URL is application A (capable of amazon S3) also able to use the presigned URL?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for Minio.

Comment: From [Minio Docs](https://docs.minio.io/): "Minio is an object storage server released under Apache License v2.0. It is compatible with Amazon S3 cloud storage service."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, minio is compatible with AWS S3. You can have your application that is currently connecting to `AWS S3` connect to `minio`.

Presigned URLs can be used by any application as long as they have not expired.

If you are just starting out on minio, please join our slack channel at https://slack.min.io